# How to display object key value?

Tags: vue.js

I need to display key value from object. Here is my code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: {"2018-05-11":{"may":4,"june":8,"april":5}}
  }
})
```

In my template I would like to display: `2018-05-11`, but not `{"2018-05-11":{"may":4,"june":8,"april":5}}`. How I can do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/grnok86b/

Comment: will `x` value always be in singular?  what yoy want to do after displaying only `key` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use computed and Object.keys for return key as value.

for example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    x: {
      "2018-05-11": {
        "may": 4,
        "june": 8,
        "april": 5
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    date() {
      return Object.keys(this.x)[0];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>My date is {{date}}</p>
</div>
```

you can loop it if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a `computed` method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: {
      "2018-05-11": {
        "may": 4,
        "june": 8,
        "april": 5
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    foo() {
      return Object.keys(this.x)[0]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ foo }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function even to do this procedure.

**HTML**

```
<p v-for="entidade in relato.entidade">${acessaEntidade(entidade)}</p>
```

The function in methods

**JS**

```
acessaEntidade: function (id) {
            return this.entidades['nome' + id]
        },
```

In the case I have a variable that is loaded and that variable there are indexes, 1, 2, 3 ... I get these indexes and consult in a new function to return the value by querying on another variable. If you need help, tell me by email :)